# How to read a complex number from keyboard ? I mean I cannot use scanf or get (in C)

Tags: c

I declare `z3` as a complex number and I want the user to enter, but I don't know how to read the real and the imaginary part and save it in `z3`. I think I can use neither scanf nor get. Here is the code.

```
void main(void)
{
    float complex z1= 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
    float complex z2= 1.0 - 4.0 * I;
    float complex z3;

    float complex sum= z1 + z2;

    printf("\nLa suma Z1+Z2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n",crealf(sum),cimagf(sum));

    printf("\nIngrese la parte real de Z3... ");
    ///??????? 
    printf("\nIngrese la parte imaginaria de Z3... ");
    ///???????
    //How can I read and saved a complex number?
}
```

Comment: `scanf` and `gets` are both inherently unsafe, so you wouldn't want to use them anyway.  Prefer `fgets`

Comment: Read text, and parse it. Also it is `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scanf like this:

```
typedef struct complex_num
{
    float f_real;
    float f_img;
}complex_num_t;

complex_num_t get_complex_num()

{
    complex_num_t complex_num= {0,0};
    printf("Enter real part:");
    scanf("%f",&complex_num.f_real);
    printf("Enter imaginery part:");
    scanf("%f",&complex_num.f_img);
    return complex_num;
}

void main(void)
{
float complex z1= 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
float complex z2= 1.0 - 4.0 * I;
float complex z3;

complex_num_t input_num = {0,0};

float complex sum= z1 + z2;

printf("\nLa suma Z1+Z2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n",crealf(sum),cimagf(sum));

/*Metod 1: Ask real and imaginary independently*/
input_num = get_complex_num();
z3 = input_num.f_real + input_num.f_img*I;

printf("\nIngrese la parte real de Z3...%f ",crealf(z3));
printf("\nIngrese la parte imaginaria de Z3...%f ",cimagf(z3));

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.. That was exactly what I was trying to do.. It works perfectly!